# best practice size ratio of $PGDATA vs archive/backups for postgres

Tags: postgresql, disk-space

we use separate logical volumes for postgresql

1. the data directory
2. a directory for daily (compressed) pg_basebackups, which are being sent to an offsite datagrave once created plus archives (also being sent away daily)

Is there any rule of thumb how the ratio between those 2 in terms of disk space should be?
At the moment we do 2:1 (data:backups) and I am wondering whether there is an "industry standard" for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection between the database size and the amount of WAL generated and archived. The latter depends entirely on the data modifying statements you run against the server.

Since you are asking for best practice:

- Best practice is *not* to store archived WAL segments on the database machine at all. Move them to different storage on a different machine right when you archive the WAL segments. Otherwise a problem on the database machine may destroy what you need for recovery. A simple solution could be an NFS share.
- As for dividing up disk space for the database, use three file systems: one for the database data, one for `pg_wal` and one for the log files. That way, neither of these can fill the disk of the others.

Comment: thx for the explanation ... we **do** move those archived walfiles away to a different system once a day (not directly though), maybe I di not make this clear enough.

Comment: You made that clear, but that means that if the machine has a problem, you will lose a lot of data. Perhaps that is OK for you, but it is certainly not best practice.

Comment: it is actually defined as a policy that loosing 6 hrs of WAL are acceptable (which I do not see any advantage in, but still it is the situation, which appranetly and strangely is acceptable for my organization).